# Use DISTANCE() function to get a column or sort by Distance for Lookup object

Tags: apex

I am trying to either use have DISTANCE as a column or Sort by DISTANCE. But the field I need to look at is at Parent level. FOr ORDERING, I got Internal Salesforce.com Error.

```
List<AccountContactRelation> accConList = [SELECT Id, Account.BilingAddress FROM AccountCOntactRelation WHERE DISTANCE(Account.BillingAddress, GEOLOCATION(:geoLatitude, :geoLongitude), 'mi') <:miles ORDER BY DISTANCE(Account.BillingAddress, GEOLOCATION(:lat, :lon), \'mi\') ASC]
```

I found this documentation where it says you need to individually bring latitude, longitude fields to get from parent to be used in DISTANCE, but I am not sure how to use that in SOQL. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/compound_fields_limitations.htm

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately DISTANCE (and possibly GEOLOCATION) cannot access the coordinate through a lookup, so:

```
DISTANCE(Account.BillingAddress, ...
```

is not valid. When I try this as a returned column, I get a query exception like "No such column".

Additionally, it isn't possible to use DISTANCE with two composed GEOLOCATIONS, so:

```
DISTANCE(GEOLOCATION(Latitude__c, Longitude__c), GEOLOCATION(...
```

is also not valid. I mention this to indicate that you **cannot** use two formula fields that get the related object's (i.e. the Account's) latitude and longitude respectively.

AFAIK, the only solution you have is to introduce a custom Geolocation type field on your AccountContactRelation and write the necessary triggers to synchronize this value from the Account's BillingAddress coordinate when a relation is created or when the Account's coordinate changes. You can then use this custom Geolocation field in your SOQL.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. One question I have is how does it let me use that lookup in WHERE clause?